# join two queries to form an result set

Tags: php, mysql

hello all i have to join two queries to form an result set :-

1st:

```
SELECT  
    orderId,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(categoryId) ORDER BY orderId SEPARATOR ', ') as catId 
FROM 
    ecart_product 
INNER JOIN ecart_orderdetail 
WHERE 
    ecart_orderdetail.productId = ecart_product.id 
group by orderId
```

this gives me

```
orderId catId
167 59, 2
168 2
169 2
170 2
171 2
172 48, 2
173 2
174 2
```

2nd:

```
select * from ecart_orders
```

in both orderId is common how could this could be join ?

Comment: can you post your table definitions? Its hard to determine what columns to be included, plus your query on top is erroneous. Have you read the basics in JOINING queries? if not try visiting this http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mean time i also solved it

```
  select * from ecart_orders Inner join(
  SELECT  
  orderId,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(categoryId) ORDER BY orderId SEPARATOR ', ')  as catId
  FROM   `ecart_product` INNER JOIN ecart_orderdetail
  WHERE ecart_orderdetail.productId =   ecart_product.id group by orderId) as c 
  on ecart_orders.id=c.orderId
```

Comment: are you sure this fixed your problem? seems still erroneous to me.

Comment: Dear Downvoter,when you accept your own answer it doesn't add reputation to your status.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `orderId` is PK in `ecart_orders` table and that it has `productId` column.
You can try this:

```
SELECT  
    orderId,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(categoryId) ORDER BY orderId SEPARATOR ', ') as catId ,
    ecart_orders.*
FROM 
    ecart_product 
INNER JOIN ecart_orderdetail 
    ON ecart_orderdetail.productId = ecart_product.id 
INNER JOIN ecart_orders
    ON ecart_orders.productId = ecart_product.id    
group by orderId
```